# how to replace label using entry and button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

so im trying to display label using search box, but each time i click the search button the new label displays right under the previous one and so I wanted for the label to just change instead of appearing under the previous one

```
Label(myWindow, text=" ").pack()
def box():
    input_ = entry_1.get()
    display = "JADWAL HARI " + input_.upper()
    label_display = Label(myWindow, font="none 16", relief="sunken")
    label_display["text"] = display
    label_display.pack()
    if (input_.upper() == "SENIN"):
        Label(myWindow, text="{}\n{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_hari[0], List.list_mapel[0], List.list_waktu[0], List.list_kelas[1], List.list_dosen[0]), font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="--------------------------------------------", font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_mapel[1], List.list_waktu[1], List.list_kelas[0], List.list_dosen[1]), font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="--------------------------------------------", font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_mapel[2], List.list_waktu[2], List.list_kelas[9], List.list_dosen[2]), font="none 14").pack()
    elif(input_.upper() == "SELASA"):
        Label(myWindow, text="{}\n{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_hari[1], List.list_mapel[3], List.list_waktu[0], List.list_kelas[8], List.list_dosen[3]), font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="--------------------------------------------", font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_mapel[1], List.list_waktu[1], List.list_kelas[0], List.list_dosen[1]), font="none 14").pack()
    elif(input_.upper() == "RABU"):
        Label(myWindow, text="{}\n{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_hari[2], List.list_mapel[3], List.list_waktu[0], List.list_kelas[8], List.list_dosen[3]), font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="--------------------------------------------", font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_mapel[4], List.list_waktu[1], List.list_kelas[0], List.list_dosen[4]), font="none 14").pack()
    elif(input_.upper() == "KAMIS"):
        Label(myWindow, text="{}\n{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_hari[3], List.list_mapel[6], List.list_waktu[1], List.list_kelas[5], List.list_dosen[6]), font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="--------------------------------------------", font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_mapel[5], List.list_waktu[0], List.list_kelas[6], List.list_dosen[5]), font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="--------------------------------------------", font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_mapel[10], List.list_waktu[3], List.list_kelas[4], List.list_dosen[10]), font="none 14").pack()
    elif(input_.upper() == "JUMAT"):
        Label(myWindow, text="{}\n{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_hari[4], List.list_mapel[7], List.list_waktu[0], List.list_kelas[2], List.list_dosen[7]), font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="--------------------------------------------", font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_mapel[8], List.list_waktu[1], List.list_kelas[2], List.list_dosen[8]), font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="--------------------------------------------", font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="{} | {} | {}\n{}".format(List.list_mapel[9], List.list_waktu[3], List.list_kelas[0], List.list_dosen[9]), font="none 14").pack()

entry_1 = Entry(myWindow)
button_1 = Button(myWindow, text="cari jadwal", command=box)

entry_1.pack()
button_1.pack()
```

Comment: There must be hundreds if not thousands of questions on this site related to updating a label. Have you done any research at all? Also, it would really help if you could condense this code down to a [mcve]. If the problem is updating a label, we don't need 4 `elseif` sections since the problem can (presumably) be reproduced in the `if` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everytime you click the search button, you actually create new labels and append to the main window.  In order to update existing label, you need to change your code as below:

```
message = Label(myWindow, text="")
message.pack()

def box():
    input_ = entry_1.get().upper()
    display = "JADWAL HARI " + input_
    if input == "SENIN":
        display += "\n......"
    elif input == "SELASA":
        display += "\n......"
    elif input == "RABU":
        display += "\n......"
    message['text'] = display     # update label
    entry_1.delete(0, END)        # clear entry
```